# Cant push after do git pull from specific branch

Tags: git

i haven't doing collaboration with other using github before so its a bit confusing, they gave me a branch to push to. Here's what i do to push my code,

```
git add .
git commit -m "Update layout, add chat app"
  69 files changed, 6657 insertions(+), 228 deletions(-)
git remote add origin https://github.com
git push -u origin myBranch
```

and then it said

```
error: src refspec myBranch does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/boryio/everytalk-app.git'
```

so i tried several solutions from stackoverflow, and i found this solution.

```
git push -f origin myBranch

 * branch            myBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Update layout, add chat app
```

then i tried this

```
git pull --rebase origin myBranch

 * branch            myBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
Created autostash: 1eb65d7
Current branch kepha is up to date.
Applied autostash.
```

but my code on github doesn't change, any idea how to fix this?

EDIT

[image]

i dont know if this was a mistake

```
git push -f origin myBranch
 * branch            myBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Update layout, add chat app
```

which like you guys said it should be

```
git pull origin myBranch
 * branch            myBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Update layout, add chat app
```

what should i do then in this state?

Comment: You are not being accurate and clear about what you said and what Git said in reply.

Comment: i vote it to close, i change my branch to new branch

Answer (score 0):

This *cannot* be what you ran and got:

> ```
> git push -f origin myBranch
>
>  * branch            myBranch     -> FETCH_HEAD
> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
> Applying: Update layout, add chat app
> ```

because the output you show is what you get from `git pull`, not from `git push`.

> ```
> git push -u origin myBranch
> error: src refspec naonvl does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/boryio/everytalk-app.git'
> ```

This also does not match up.  The first `error` line says that you do not have a branch named `naonvl`.  Your `git push` command specifies a branch named `myBranch`.

It seems likely that `naonvl` was a typo: that you named the branch `naoval`, for instance.  The fix for that would be to correct your typo.

(It's important, when posting a question, to use a great deal of care that you don't make it impossible for others to help you.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Comment: actually naonvl is my branch, i forgot to change that one

Comment: iprovide u with an img

Comment: OK, at least the *names* match up in the image. However, the *output* from `git push` is what you'd get from `git pull`. Also, `git add .` should not make a new *commit*, yet we see the result of `git commit` immediately after the `git add`. Something is seriously wrong with this setup.

Comment: yeah i know, so i create a new branch then delete previous branch